# How to use tkinter to bind operators like +-*/?

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, operators, keyboard-events

i want to use `bind` in `tkinter` to detect if `+-*/` is pressed. Is this possible? i've checked a lot on the internet and here is the code,i want to know what should i filed in the `???`

```
import tkinter as tk


class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.title('test')
        self.geometry('300x500')
        self.bind('???', lambda event: self.plus)
        self.bind('???', lambda event: self.subtraction)
        self.bind('???', lambda event: self.multiplication)
        self.bind('???', lambda event: self.division)

    def plus(self):
        print('+ is pressed')

    def subtraction(self):
        print('- is pressed')

    def multiplication(self):
        print('* is pressed')

    def division(self):
        print('/ is pressed')


def main():
    app = Application()
    app.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind to the actual characters:

```
self.bind('+', lambda event: self.plus())
self.bind('-', lambda event: self.subtraction())
self.bind('*', lambda event: self.multiplication())
self.bind('/', lambda event: self.division())
```

You can also use the following keysyms:

```
self.bind('<plus>', lambda event: self.plus())
self.bind('<minus>', lambda event: self.subtraction())
self.bind('<asterisk>', lambda event: self.multiplication())
self.bind('<slash>', lambda event: self.division())
```

For a list of all keysyms see [keysyms](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/keysyms.html) in the canonical tcl/tk documentation.